# My ASP.NET Web application runs normally on IIS express but not when I publish it

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

So I am making a mobile application with Xamarin with a ASP.NET backend. When testing the backend, I can do everything perfectly fine for ex. I can browse to localhost:port/api/user/info. But when I try exactly the same thing when I have published the site to IIS version 10.0 it gives me a 404 NOT FOUND error that there is noting found on every link.

This is the result when I run it in Visual Studio with IIS Express:
[Result from IIS Express](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tJy1.png)

This is the result when I run it via IIS:
[Result from IIS Server 10.0.18362.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Mnqe.png)

[When I go to `localhost` with IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlYCQ.png)

[When I try `localhost/backend/api/user/info/52` with IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUkPg.png)

[When I try `localhost/api/user/info/52` with IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsDsp.png)

[This error might be something leading towards a solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ibDu.png)

Maybe it has something to do with the way I publish it or in how I make the server, but I have no idea on how I could do it diffrent.

Here you have a controller I use:

```cs
namespace WebBackEnd.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/stock")]
    public class StockController : ApiController
    {
        IReadStock readStock = new ReadStockImpl();

        // GET api/stock/info/{id}
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("info/{id}")]
        public string GetStockInfo(string id)
        {
            IReadStock.StockInfoRequest request = new IReadStock.StockInfoRequest(id);
            IReadStock.StockInfoResponse response = readStock.getStockInfo(request);
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
        }
    }
}
```

I have seen some things that the web.config might have something to do with this, but I can't figure it out!

This is my web.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>     
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Kind regards Jasper Baetslé

Comment: In IIS you probably published your app under a name. Try `localhost` only first to make sure IIS is up and all. Then try `localhost/nameOfYourApp/API/user/info/52`.

Comment: Do you have the ASP.Net Windows features installed? Looks like IIS is trying to serve just Static File. Maybe you have created web site and not 'application' in IIS?

Comment: In IIS find the name of your application on the left side. I am pretty sure the name is not `backend`. Lastly the errors you're posting are not in English so I don't understand it.

Comment: Yea sorry for the errors I don't know how I can switch it to English and @Milney I did indeed make a web site I think

Comment: I don't know how I would configure a application though

Comment: Did you check IIS to make sure you published correctly, your site is pointing to your published code

Comment: Yeah Idk how I should publish it correctly, does anyone have some kind of tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you install the iis below-mentioned feature:
WebServer(ISS)->WebServer->Application Development, .NET Extensibility 3.5,.NET Extensibility 4.5,ASP.NET 4.5,ISAPI Extensions, ISAPI Filters.

and unlock the handler by using below steps:

1)Open IIS Manager

2)Select the server in the Connections pane

3)Double click Configuration Editor from the middle pane

[image]

4)In the Sections drop-down, select the section to unlock, system.webServer > handler

5)Click Unlock Attribute in the right pane

[image]

Restart IIS.

Comment: @JasperB if your issue is resolved I request you to mark the post as an answer. it will help other people who face a similar issue.